# Finding the limit of a summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of the following expression-
$$\sum_{r =1}^{n}\frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2}$$

I tried to write the expression as $$\frac{(3n+r)-(r-3n)}{(3n-r)(3n+r)}$$ and then separating the numerator in the hope of getting a telescoping series but that didn’t happen, can someone help me out.

Comment: Try Riemann sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Riemann sum, we have$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r =1}^{n}\frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{r =1}^{n}\frac{6}{9-\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{6}{9-x^2}\, dx$$

Comment: Yeah i got the answer with this method, thanks a lot, out of curiosity, do you think there’s a way to solve this without Riemann sum?

Comment: hmmm can't think of other strategy for now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2} = \frac{1}{3n-r} + \frac{1}{3n+r}$$ so that $$S(n) = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{6n}{9n^2-r^2} = -\frac{1}{3n} + \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{1}{2n+k} = -\frac{1}{3n} + H_{4n} - H_{2n-1},$$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ harmonic number.  Then as $n \to \infty$, $$H_n \sim \log n + \gamma + \mathcal O(1/n),$$  so $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S(n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \log 4n - \log 2n + \mathcal O(1/n) = \log 2.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering.